# Julianday get day of year

Tags: algorithm

I have julianday like 731831, how i can get day of year from it?

Comment: We need to know more about your Julian format. Do you have a Julian date and the year/month/day it corresponds to?

Answer (score 0):

That's a rather low Julian Day Number.

And remember that days *start* when the fractional part of the JD is *.5*

If you plug 731831 into the USNO's converter it gives

`BCE 2710 August 24 12:00:00.0 UT  Wednesday`

In other words *noon* on a Wednesday.

*I just wonder if the ancient people of that time thought of it as Wednesday?*

Comment: It looks like his years start at zero, and his example is in 2005 sometime.

Comment: Ah, so it's probably a modified Julian Day number, and that's why you asked for an example JD and calendar date.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a solved problem.  Your best bet is to get a library where someone else wrote and debugged the code for you.

If you can use Python, here is a simple example: http://katamari.ssec.wisc.edu/resources/scriptonomicon/julian-day-to-calendar-day

If you really want to write it yourslelf, I suggest a Google search for "Julian conversion algorithm".  I ran that search and here is a good result: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp